# Problema al subir archivos pesados con php

Tags: php, php5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en la cual se pueden subir al servidor: imágenes, archivos y videos.

Este es mi código php:

```
<?php
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);
 $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], "archivos/" . $name);
?>
```

Cuando se sube imágenes o archivos todo funciona bien pero cuando se trata de subir videos viene el problema php me arroja el siguiente error:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 72892057 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

He configurado mi archivo php.ini de la siguiente manera:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. 
upload_max_filesize = 1000M 

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept. 
post_max_size = 1000M 

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds        
max_execution_time = 100     

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data 
max_input_time = 60 

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)  
memory_limit = 10M
```

Pero no consigo hacer que se puedan subir archivos pesados como lo son los videos.

Comment: Mira con la función phpinfo() si realmente has modificado los valores.

Comment: @track3r no están cambiando los valores, por que no los cambia??

Comment: debes reiniciar el servidor apache! despues de hacer cualquier configuracion!

Comment: @Bryro lo se pero el problema estaba en que en mi servidor tengo instaladas dos versiones de php, entonces no estaba configurando el archivo ini de la versión php que tengo ejecutando